# Auto clicking using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

By using selenium click, I'm looking to auto download the subtitles that has **'TXT Korean'** in their button tags in the webpage source. I am trying to collect Korean subtitles data for data collection.

the code below opens the website fine, but wouldn't click the **'TXT 한국어'** part and giving me errors.

**The sourcecode from the website**

`<button type="button" class="ma-1 download-button v-btn v-btn--depressed v-btn--flat v-btn--outlined theme--light v-size--default primary--text" data-title="[TXT] 한국어"><span class="v-btn__content"><i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left material-icons theme--light">save_alt</i><button type="button" class="primary v-btn v-btn--depressed v-btn--rounded theme--light v-size--x-small"><span class="v-btn__content">TXT</span></button></span></button>`

**Python Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/ccc/Desktop/chromedriver.exe') 
driver.get('https://downsub.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ted.com%2Ftalks%2Frachel_kleinfeld_a_path_to_security_for_the_world_s_deadliest_countries%3Flanguage%3Dko%27language%3D%27ko%2r')
elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='layout justify-start']//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']")
elements.click()
```

**ERROR**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\down.py", line 5, in <module>
    elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='layout justify-start']//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']")
  File "C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath       
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\ccc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='layout justify-start']//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)

PS C:\Users\ccc\Desktop> [18904:19076:0928/165026.096:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[18904:19076:0928/165026.332:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(963)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -113
[7460:6468:0928/165026.860:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [16:50:26.860] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1074 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

Comment: Please try and relook into the structure. The element you are trying to find in order to click seems to be missing (not present in the DOM). Also it would really help if you could make your approach/problem bit more clear. In terms of what you want to achieve exactly and where exactly do you need help. That will really help us to help you quickly

Comment: elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']") would work btw.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Tanishq, I mended the question so.

Comment: I tried with your code snippet but would throw same errors :/

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your code in Java, **the code worked fine**, no error happened.

So, just according to your below error message, there are some suggests you could try

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='layout justify-start']//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']"}
```

1. try this kind of xpath expression

```
"//button[contains(@data-title,'[TXT]') and contains(@data-title,'한국어')]"
```

2. scroll down to the element before clicking on it

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elements)
elements.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Peter, it would throw same error :/ It doesn't seem like my computer setting or Chrome setting is blocking this as I set it all as 'Unproteced mode' on Security setting.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Peter answered, let me give you little more insight, Your desired element is not displaying in current view, That's why Selenium is throwing you this exception.
You need to scroll down to that element and then click it.
It will do the trick.

```
elements = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='layout justify-start']//button[@data-title='[TXT] 한국어']") //Element declaration

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elements) //Scroll down to that element
elements.click() //Click on element
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Taimoor, It throws the same error ..:/

Comment: Put wait on that of 'Until element is clickable'